# Querying and viewing Sitecore logs in managed cloud

Tags: sitecore-managed-cloud

Currently upgrading to 10.2 and migrating to SC managed Cloud as part of this project.  We are having a few issues after our first image deployment. I would like to view the SC logs. Its my understanding that the Sitecore logs are exported into Elastic Search. How do we access Elastic Search to view / query the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still have some access to the services in Azure - for my project running in Managed Cloud in containers (Kubernetes) I can use kubectl to show the logs. For debugging purposes I found this to be the fastest way.

But you can also use Kibana (open-source data visualization tool used to show the logs stored in ElasticSearch). Check https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/managed-cloud/getting-started-with-managed-cloud-standard.html on how to access Kibana. I wrote a small part about it in my blog https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2022/03/sitecore-managed-cloud-SXA-jss-nextjs.html :

> **Kibana**
>
> This might sound like a sunny Brazilian beach but it's actually the
> place to find your logs - based on Elastic Search. You'll find the
> information in the Sitecore docs, your url and login information in
> the secrets and you're good to go.
>
> If you are not used to this environment it can be a bit tricky to find what you are looking for. First of all: find the
> navigation - and go to "Discover" in the "Analytics section.   You
> should get a lot of entries that might make no sense so you need to
> start filtering. The servicename is a good place to start: those will
> be like "sitecore-xm1-cm" and so on. The pod_name can also be useful
> if you know it. Best way for me was start simple and check the results
> to see which fields are available and can be used to filter further to
> get the logs needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am now into Kibana and querying.  I have a another question but I will create another question